# How to detect Multiple QRcode at once using Vision api?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, vision

I have five qr codes in a row like the below image
[image: qr code values->Hello my name is lip]
i am using google Vision api

```
override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
            val barcodes = detections?.detectedItems
            if (barcodes!!.size() > 0) {
                for (index in 0..barcodes.size()-1){
                    Log.e("Scanned value"," "+barcodes.valueAt(index).displayValue)
                }
                Log.e("Scanned value"," ---------------------------------------------------")

            }
        }
```

But in detections sparseArray i am not getting all the values,only one or two values,how i can read process all the five qr codes and returns the result like "Hello my name is lipu"?

Comment: If the QR codes are always in the same position and have the same sizes then you could split up the image.

Comment: can you suggest some codes or links @FrancescoRe

Comment: Well, the code depends on the way the image is acquired, the compression format of the image and other parameters.

Comment: if the image is fixed as the image i have shared in the question.. - FrancescoRe